# Xcode memory graph debugger to see what an object is referencing

Tags: xcode

In the Xcode memory graph debugger you can click on an object in memory and see what is referencing it.

For example... you might have an object `Car` being referenced by an object `Person` with the `vehicle` property.

If you click on the `Car` you can see the `Person` and the property reference name.

But... if you click on the `Person` you can no longer see the car. Is there a way to make it show what `Person` is referencing? It will show the `Car` but may also who other things being held by the `Person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible in the memory graph debugger, but if it's a feature you'd like to see, you should file an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com outlining your use case.

Comment: Thanks. Will add a radar.